# Is there any multiplatform language?

Tags: .net, programming-languages, jvm

I need something that can be run both on JVM and .NET. What is the best option to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)?

Comment: The End of IKVM.NET was in 2017. http://weblog.ikvm.net/CommentView.aspx?guid=33ea525f-a291-418a-bd6a-abdf22d0662b

Answer (score 2):

Python, perhaps?  Jython for Java, and IronPython for .NET

Another option is Scala, however I have yet to actually play with that...

Answer (score 2):

[Clojure](http://clojure.org) can be run on the JVM and CLR, but the JVM support is currently much better.

Comment: Interesting langauge, that's been on my list of languages to learn for a short while...  Why do you say that the JVM support is much better - is it more reliable? Supports more of the API? In what way is .NET support lacking?

Comment: Clojure in its own right is a fantastic language.  It also gains a lot from having terrific interop with java, and most libraries seem geared towards working with java or are java only.  The development of the CLR version of Clojure also tends to lag behind.  That being said, just using the core of Clojure that is compatible is still a great language and worth learning.

Comment: +1, then - I'll move it higher in my list of languages to learn, then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe better your requirements? if you need to port a program across platforms ( aka Mac, Linux, Windows... ) it does not mean you need it to run inside JVM and also inside .NET

For example, if you would use pure Java, by definition it would run inside a specific JVM in all those environments, to do kind of the same with .NET, there is Mono for non windows platforms.

what do you want to do exactly with your program?

Comment: There are some platforms where only one of them is available directly. For example WP7 only supports .net, and Android by default only supports Java(Unless you buy MonoDroid, and that has its share of disadvantages).

Comment: Actually, Android does NOT support Java. It won't support any of the dynamic bytecode, which means Jython and other languages that run on the JVM won't work, Scala /might/ work, but not sure - generally it would have to explicitly support whatever it is that Android uses.

Answer (score 1):

Python via Jython and IronPython probably has the best support. There are others such as Ruby, Fantom, Scala etc but the .Net support is often lagging behind Java.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you would like to build a client application that you can deploy and run on any platform. That sounds a bit like magic. If you find something that works for Windows and Android, it may very well not run on the next platform you need to deploy your application on (iOS?).

Not clear what the application does or how heavy it needs to be, but if you move all the weight of your client application to a server, you can then quickly build thin distinct clients that are compatible with the platforms they need to run on, and you can ask the server to do all the heavy lifting and communicate results back over standard protocols like JSON/XML over HTTP.